# How to change related entities using event listeners with doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Symfony and Doctrine, I have a `User` entity and a `Address` entity. Every user can have 0 or more addresses and one of them is his default address.

So when I change the default address from one to another I should set that one to default and the others to not default (a boolean field).

I tried to do so with event listeners so when the `Address` entity is updated I launched the post updated event setting all the other addresses to non default, something like this:

```
class AddresssListener
{
    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof Address) {
            $this->changeDefaultAddress($entity, $event);
        }
    }

    private function changeDefaultAddress($address, $event)
    {
        if ($address->getIsDefault() == true) {
            foreach ($address->getUser()->getBillingDatas() as $another_address) {
                if ($address != $another_address) {
                    $another_address->setIsDefault(false);
                    $em = $event->getEntityManager();
                    $em->persist($another_address);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code is executed correctly and no error is displayed, but the changes on the non default addresses are not saved.

Comment: are you aware that you are not persisting the object you updated? you updated $another_address and you persist $another_billing_data

Comment: hi, sorry, my fault. I corrected the code in the question. Yes, I persis another_address

Comment: And where is flush() method? And, why you instantiating em every time in foreach loop?

Comment: I tried with flush as well and it didn't work either. I should move the em instantiation out of the loop, true

Comment: Your posted code still does not show the flush for $another_address.  Doctrine events are tricky.  I would strongly suggest adding a changeDefaultAddress to the user object and moving the logic to it.

Comment: You may try to call recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet() as described in this post: http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/update-associated-entities-in-doctrine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `User` can only have one default `Address` you should also somehow make sure your database model only supports one address to be the default one.

I would suggest to make the `Address` which is  the current default address to a relation of `User` (an additional One-To-One association between `Address` (`$defaultAddress`) and `User` next to your One-To-Many relation with addresses). Then you can simply do like this:

```
$user->setDefaultAddress($address);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

This can be done with one database operation vs two in your example (PostPersist is called after the flush of the first operation)

And now it is easy to get the current default address:

```
$address = $user->getDefaultAddress();
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and will make the default address visible in the data schema. Thanks!